Multiple WiFi devices and interfaces - bind connection to specific interface
Currently using Raspbian/bookworm in default configuration 'NetworkManager' is used to connect to WiFi networks. If you use at least one additional WiFi-device on your RaspberryPi, you will have more than one wlan* interface. In my example I use a RaspberryPi 3B which has onboard WiFi, then I plugged in an USB-WiFi adapter, so I have two interfaces:

wlan0 (RaspberryPi's own WiFi interface)
wlan1 (the additional USB-WiFi adapter interface)

Since the WiFi connections seems not to be interface bound in NetworkManager, the connection switches uncontrolled between wlan0 interface and wlan1 interface every now and then (as also sometimes between reboots).
NetworkManager has following configured in
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/preconfigured.nmconnection
[connection]
id=preconfigured
uuid=8043d3ca-6cb6-4449-83c4-61539463af66
type=wifi
[wifi]
mode=infrastructure
ssid=myhomenetwork
hidden=false
[ipv4]
method=auto
[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=default
method=auto
[proxy]
[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=ec6f<snip>128e

The integrated WiFi device (=wlan0) of RaspberryPi obviously has less signal strength to myhomenetwork than the USB-WiFi adapter, so I want to use the USB-WiFi adapter (=wlan1) to connect to myhomenetwork.
(I want to use the internal WiFi device to connect to another nearby WiFi AP)
For that reason I try to bind the connection to myhomenetwork on wlan1 interface.
According to the NetworkManager documentation this should be done by defining interface-name under [connection].
The documentation states to that property: "The name of the network interface this connection is bound to. If not set, then the connection can be attached to any interface of the appropriate type..."
So I added interface-name=wlan1 like this:
[connection]
id=preconfigured
uuid=8043d3ca-6cb6-4449-83c4-61539463af66
type=wifi
interface-name=wlan1

But even after I have set the interface-name, after a reboot that 'preconfigured.nmconnection' still uses wlan0.
I'm wondering why this is the case and how to force that connection to interface wlan1.

Does this answer help?

Thanks for the hint, I tried that and the output of that command was Device 'wlan1' successfully activated with '8043d3ca-6cb6-4449-83c4-61539463af66'. Further I noticed it rewrote the preconfigured.nmconnection file (and added timestamp= property to [connection]), but nothing else changed. Issue still persists.

mmm... so now you know why I say, "NetworkManager sux"  Suggestion: follow up w/ the author of that post via comment.

After much poking around and several reinstalls I guess I figured it out.
Editing the .nmconnection file directly seems not to be a good idea. Even with using nmcli connection reload and/or rebooting, this does not work properly and confuses networkmanager.
By using only the nmcli command from the beginning after a clean install it seems to work as expected.
So to achieve what I asked, just run following two commands:
nmcli connection modify preconfigured connection.interface-name wlan1
nmcli device wifi connect myhomenetwork ifname wlan1

Where "preconfigured" is the id/name of the configured connection, "myhomenetwork" is the SSID of my wifi network and "wlan1" is the interface where the connection should be bound to.
To show the id/name of all configured connections you can use:
nmcli connection

